# How to modify axios instance after exported it in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
```

to set header after user make login in application, but when refresh the page this configuration is removed.

I would like to set this configuration for all requests from axios, when user make login.

I got do that setting this configuration manually, putting this line of code before to export axios instance.

Now, I need to set this configuration when user make login. How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're probably going to want to write a middleware module to get/set the token in `localStorage` and apply it to your Axios instance. In the past when I used Axios, I typically did it like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_URL } from '../constants/api';

const API = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${API_URL}`,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

API.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const token = sessionStorage.getItem('jwt');

    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    } else {
      delete API.defaults.headers.common.Authorization;
    }
    return config;
  },

  error => Promise.reject(error)
);

export default API;
```

You'll need to create functions to get/set the JWT in `localStorage`, but if you do that, this should work for you. This will fetch the JWT from `localStorage` before making each request, so it won't break even if the page is refreshed as long as the user has a valid JWT in `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as Hiatt described:
refresh the page will invalidate my previous default config

while I don't feel like **reading storage** before every request
so what I did is **check before request** and **read if necessary** (eg: default were reset due to page reload

```
// request interceptor function
function check_before_request(config) {
  if (! config.headers.common['Authorization']) {
    const token = Cookies.get('Authorization')
    if (! token){
      removeCookies()
      location.href = `/login?redirect=${encodeURIComponent(location.pathname)}`
    }
    else {
      setHeaderAuth(token, config)
    }
    return config
  }
  else return config
}
```

```
// also can be used in login page but without the second param
function setHeaderAuth(token, config) {
  Cookies.set('Authorization', token)
  axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
  if (config){
    config.headers['Authorization'] = token
  }
}
```